# Align horizontally three TextView blocks

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to align three blocks of textview in my Android application. This is the situation: I have the first block (Release date) correctly aligned on the left and the third block (Language) correctly aligned on the right. Now, I'm trying to place the second block at the center, between the two above, but a you can see it goes on the left on first block.

[image]
This is the code:

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/container">

        <!-- BLOCK 1 -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/releaseDateHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Release Date"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/releaseDateHeader"
            android:id="@+id/releaseDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            tools:text="ff"/>

        <!-- BLOCK 2 -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/runtimeHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Runtime"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/releaseDateHeader"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/runtimeHeader"
            android:id="@+id/runtimeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            tools:text="ff"/>

        <!-- BLOCK 3 -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/countryHeader"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Language"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/countryHeader"
            android:id="@+id/countryTextView"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            tools:text="ff"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/desired_id_1"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/desired_id_2"
```

it makes `View` align its left edge to right edge of `desired_id_1` and right edge to left edge of `desired_id_2`

so `runtimeHeader` should be `toRightOf` `countryHeader` and `toLeftOf` `releaseDateHeader`. also remove `layout_alignRight`

besides that you have two rows, so they should be in separated `ViewGroup`s. Also in you case `LinearLAyout` with orientation set to hoizontal may be more convenient

Answer (score 2):

Same design as of yours

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Orders"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="12"
                android:id="@+id/orderCount"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Wishlist"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/wishlistCount"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Wishlist"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/wishlistCount2"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_weight` like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="3">

  <!-- BLOCK 1 -->

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/releaseDateHeader"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Release Date"
      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <TextView
      android:layout_below="@id/releaseDateHeader"
      android:id="@+id/releaseDateTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:text="ff"/>

  <!-- BLOCK 2 -->

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/runtimeHeader"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Runtime"
      android:layout_alignRight="@id/releaseDateHeader"
      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can also do using constraint layout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/container"
    android:background="#000000">

    <!-- BLOCK 1 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseDateHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Release Date"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseDateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/releaseDateHeader"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/releaseDateHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/releaseDateHeader"
        tools:text="ff" />

    <!-- BLOCK 2 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runtimeHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/releaseDateHeader"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Runtime"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/countryHeader"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/releaseDateHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/releaseDateHeader" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runtimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/runtimeHeader"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/runtimeHeader"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/runtimeHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/runtimeHeader"
        tools:text="ff" />

    <!-- BLOCK 3 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Language"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/releaseDateHeader" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/countryHeader"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/countryHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryHeader"
        tools:text="ff" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```